# How do I work out Content-Length dynamically?

Tags: php, api, https

This is how I'm calling an API in PHP. In order to use it, I need Content-Length. I'm not sure what the content length would be as the body will always be changing depending on the variables I pass though - I may also add extra lines into the body. What is the best way to calculate content-length in this context?

```
$opts = array();
$opts = [
    "http" => [
            "method" => "POST",
            "header" => "Header1: xxx \r\n"  .
            "Header2: xxx \r\n"  .
            "Content-Length: ???", <---------???
            "body" => "FirstName: FirstName \r\n"  .
            "LastName: LastName \r\n"  .
            "AddressLine1: Ad1  \r\n"  .
            "AddressLine2: Ad2  \r\n"  .
            "AddressLine3: Ad3  \r\n"  .
            "AddressLine4: Ad4  \r\n"  .
            "AddressLine5: Ad5  \r\n"  .
            "Telephone: Telephone  \r\n"  .
            "EmailAddress: EmailAddress  \r\n"  .
            ]
        ];

$context = stream_context_create($opts);
$url = 'https://url.com/endpoint';
$file = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);

echo $file;

?>
```

Comment: generate the body content before $opts, get `strlen` of the body and use that perhaps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the example below at https://www.sk89q.com/2010/04/introduction-to-php-streams:

```
$postdata = array(
  'var1' => 'value1',
  'var2' => 'value2',
);

$opts = array('http' =>
  array(
    'method'  => 'POST',
    'header'  => 'Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'content' => http_build_query($postdata, '', '&'),
    'timeout' => 5,
  )
);

$context = stream_context_create($opts);

echo file_get_contents("http://example.com", 0, $context);
```

This suggests that content-length might not be needed.

If I combine this with the first note here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.stream-context-create.php

I get:

```
$postdata = http_build_query(['var1' => 'value1',
                              'var2' => 'value2'],'','&'));

$opts = array('http' =>
  array(
    'method'  => 'POST',
    'header'  => "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n".
                 'Content-Length: '.strlen($postData)."\r\n",
    'content' => $postData,
    'timeout' => 5,
  )
);

$context = stream_context_create($opts);

echo file_get_contents("http://example.com", 0, $context);
```

Could that work for you? I do notice that you call the content 'body', but that's up to you.